# How to check if a string contains both letters and numbers?

Tags: java

How can I check that the string contains both letters and numbers, both? As in the following example:

```
nickname1
nick1name
1nickname
```

I've seen a few examples of patterns, but none solves my problem, even most don't work

The situation is that in the application that I'm creating username must be a letter and number, so I need this...

Comment: so? check it with a few regexes.

Comment: You can check stackoverflow.com/a/11533559/290036 but with [a-zA-Z]

Comment: How is this Question too broad? Seems like a very specific problem to me. Thus I was able to give a very specific Answer. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Unicode & `Character` class

What exactly do you mean by a letter? By a number?

Unicode defines those terms across the various human languages. In Java, the [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html) class provides convenient access to those definitions.

We can make short work of this using streams. Calling [`String::codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) generates an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html). We can test each code point for being a letter or digit, until we find one.

```
String input = "nickname1" ;
boolean hitLetter = input.codePoints().anyMatch( i -> Character.isLetter( i ) ) ;
boolean hitDigit = input.codePoints().anyMatch( i -> Character.isDigit( i ) ) ; ;
boolean containsBoth = ( hitLetter && hitDigit ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/rYz9hF).

Answer (score 1):

Well maybe this can help you

```
String myUser = "asdsad213213";
if(myUser.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")){

 //this is true
}
```

OR create a pattern

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputstring);
if (m.find()){
//true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private boolean checkUsername(String username)
{
String characters = "^[a-zA-Z]+$";
String numbers = "^[0-9]+$";

return username.matches(numbers) && username.matches(characters);
}
```

there you go, it first for numbers then for chars and when both exist you get a true value